# Russian in lists in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a='Привет'
print a
b=[]
b.append(a)
print b
```

Here is code, which has to print `Привет`

```
['Привет']
```

But when I run this code, it prints `Привет`

```
['\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82']
```

Unfortunately, it does not print what I need. Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Read this -> http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behaviour you see is *normal*. You have a UTF-8 encoded byte string, and when printing a list, Python will always show such strings as Python string literals in their most portable form.

You really want to use Unicode values, and print individual items from the list:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = u'Привет'  # Unicode literal
print a
b = []
b.append(a)
print b[0]     # print individual item
```

If you don't yet know the difference between Unicode and a byte string or anything much about codecs, I urge you to read:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

before you continue.

Answer (score 2):

When printing lists, Python will use the `repr` function on the elements inside it.

The `repr` function for strings in Python 2.x will make it 100% ascii compatible to avoid problems like wrong encoding in your terminal.

You have to iterate your list and print each element.

Also, I advise you to use `unicode` strings for text (even more important if it is not ascii).